# Change on mouseover to on mouseclick

Tags: html, triggers, mouseover

I have the following script that works a treat showing a hidden div when the image in hovered over. However when I have a lot of text in the hidden div, that I need to scroll down to view, as soon as I come off the mouseover img the text disappears.

Is there a way that I can get the text to stay until the next image is hovered over or for the text to stay with a mouseclick? I changed the first part of the script to mouseclick, with no luck.

Many thanks for your help.

```
<div onmouseover="document.getElementById('pop-up-box1').style.display = 'block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('pop-up-box1').style.display = 'none';">
    <div id="pop-up-trigger1">
       <img onmouseover="this.src='http://griffithsandpartners.com.gridhosted.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Services-banking-black.png';" onmouseout="this.src='http://griffithsandpartners.com.gridhosted.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Services-banking-White.png';" alt="" src="http://griffithsandpartners.com.gridhosted.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Services-banking-White.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: welcome to SO, please show your script and html

Comment: I that case i suggest you to show the hidden div on mouse click instead of mouseover

Comment: @Lyndsay can we use jQuery for this?

Comment: what would the code be for mouse click? I have tried mouse click, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

OK.

Have found it. It's just "on click" !